# XSLT 1.0 Add Incrementing RowNumber Per Group

Tags: xml, xslt

I have flat XML data that I want to transform, including sorting by the date value and adding an incrementing row number.

I have the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
    <_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
        <InceptionDate>01/01/2021</InceptionDate>
        <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
        <UMR>A</UMR>
    </_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
    <_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
        <InceptionDate>02/02/2021</InceptionDate>
        <FirstName>Theo</FirstName>         
        <UMR>A</UMR>
    </_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
    <_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
        <InceptionDate>03/03/2021</InceptionDate>
        <FirstName>Laura</FirstName>            
        <UMR>A</UMR>
    </_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
    <_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
        <InceptionDate>01/01/2021</InceptionDate>
        <FirstName>Sarah</FirstName>        
        <UMR>B</UMR>
    </_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
    <_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
        <InceptionDate>02/02/2021</InceptionDate>
        <FirstName>Gary</FirstName>         
        <UMR>B</UMR>
    </_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
    <_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
        <InceptionDate>03/03/2021</InceptionDate>
        <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>          
        <UMR>B</UMR>
    </_x0037_906aa9f-c0f8-4909-baa9-ba3090d6c6e5>
</NewDataSet>
```

Which I need to transform into the following format:

```
<Instances>
   <Instance>
      <formdata>
         <data>
            <UMR>A</UMR>
            <Table TableId="Details">
               <TableRow RowNumber="">
                  <InceptionDate>01/01/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="">
                  <InceptionDate>02/02/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Theo</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="">
                  <InceptionDate>03/03/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Laura</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
         </data>
      </formdata>
   </Instance>
   <Instance>
      <formdata>
         <data>
            <UMR>B</UMR>
            <Table TableId="Details">
               <TableRow RowNumber="">
                  <InceptionDate>01/01/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Sarah</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="">
                  <InceptionDate>02/02/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Gary</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="">
                  <InceptionDate>03/03/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
         </data>
      </formdata>
   </Instance>
</Instances>
```

I have the following XSLT Style Sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<!-- set up the key. -->
    <xsl:key name="UMRItems" match="NewDataSet/*" use="UMR"/>

    <!-- Matches the whole dataset and creates a copy-->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Matches NewDataSet element and replaces with Instances element -->
    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
        <Instances>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('UMRItems', UMR)[1])]"/>
        </Instances>    
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Matches the GUID element and replaces with Instance element -->
    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet/*">
        <Instance>
            <formdata>
                <data>
                    <!-- Selects non-table form data -->
                    <UMR><xsl:value-of select="UMR"/></UMR>
        
                    <Table>
                        <xsl:attribute name="TableId">
                            <xsl:text>Details</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('UMRItems', UMR)">
                        <xsl:sort select="InceptionDate"/>
                            <xsl:call-template name="TableDetails"></xsl:call-template>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Table>    
                </data>
            </formdata>
        </Instance> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="TableDetails">
            <TableRow RowNumber="" > 
                <InceptionDate><xsl:value-of select="InceptionDate"/></InceptionDate>
                <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
            </TableRow>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I expect the following output:

```
<Instances>
   <Instance>
      <formdata>
         <data>
            <UMR>A</UMR>
            <Table TableId="Details">
               <TableRow RowNumber="1">
                  <InceptionDate>01/01/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="2">
                  <InceptionDate>02/02/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Theo</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="3">
                  <InceptionDate>03/03/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Laura</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
         </data>
      </formdata>
   </Instance>
   <Instance>
      <formdata>
         <data>
            <UMR>B</UMR>
            <Table TableId="Details">
               <TableRow RowNumber="1">
                  <InceptionDate>01/01/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Sarah</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="2">
                  <InceptionDate>02/02/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Gary</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
               <TableRow RowNumber="3">
                  <InceptionDate>03/03/2021</InceptionDate>
                  <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
         </data>
      </formdata>
   </Instance>
</Instances>
```

However I am unable to generate the RowNumbers which should increment per Table.

I have tried using:

```
 Position()
```

but this results in all RowNumbers = 1

```
count(preceding::UMR[(preceding::UMR= .)])+1
```

This seems closer but only increments rows 1 and 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="UMRItems" match="/NewDataSet/*" use="UMR"/>

<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <Instances>
        <!-- a group for each distinct UMR value  -->
        <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('UMRItems', UMR)[1])]">
            <Instance>
                <formdata>
                    <data>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="UMR"/>
                        <Table TableId="Details">
                            <!-- a row for each member of current group  -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('UMRItems', UMR)">
                                <TableRow RowNumber="{position()}">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="InceptionDate | FirstName"/>
                                </TableRow>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Table>
                    </data>
                </formdata>
            </Instance>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Instances>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! this solves my problem. I really appreciate the swift reply, this has been something i have been trying for some time now!

Comment: Note that your stylesheet would have worked too if you had `<TableRow RowNumber="{position()}">` in the `TableDetails` template. But there is no good reason to have all that extra code.